# What SQL Server Login is used for SQL Server Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, database, security

I am trying to figure out what SQL Server Login gets used when I connect to SQL Server, in code, via a connection string that specifies `Integrated Security=No` and then specifies a user and password.

Note that I don't mean the user I'm specifying (I do know that of course), but the login that user maps to. I'm just now reading about logins vs users in SQL Server, and one point that is hammered home is that you always, always, always need a login to connect, and then a user per database that login needs to access. So I am looking in SSMS for the login that maps to the user I always specify on the databases I care about, but I see no such login.

Fyi, the reason I am asking, is I need to permission a new legacy app for this database, and the app is coded to use SQL Server authentication. I am trying to determine if I simply need users on the necessary database, or if I need to create a login. But now I've gotten myself curious about the general question itself.

Edit - a quick query of syslogins shows only 2 logins. So, my theory that SQLS was maintaining trivial '1 per user' logins but SSMS was hiding them, appears not to be the case

Edit - Querying syslogins, or sys.server_principals, appears to be misleading. On a database for which I have 2 different working SQLS (not Win) logins, I logged in as each and did select * from sys.server_principals. Two different answers: each time I got sa and the login I was logged in as. I would not see the 'other' login, though it was clearly there. I am guessing this may have something to do with schemas, which I also know little about. In any case, I am guessing that generally, logins do in fact exist for all users, though I will not see all these logins when I connect to SSMS as any one login. Does this sound right?

**Solved (sort of)**
From playing around, on a database on which I have sa, it is clear that SSMS only shows you all logins if you are sa, or perhaps have that specific permission. Otherwise, your view of logins is restricted. Therefore there is no real mystery as to why I was not seeing logins I was expecting. Apparently SSMS hides them. I say 'sort of' and 'apparently' because I never came across anything documenting this. It is just an observation.

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, you specify a Login in the connstr, not a User (although it is called User).

Comment: Where are you looking? At the server under Security > Logins or at the database under Security > Users?

Comment: Or somewhere completely different if it's sql server 2000. :(

Comment: I am looking at Database > Security > Users and seeing the User I am expecting to see. And I am looking under Server > Security > Logins and not seeing a corresponding login. That is why I am confused. Does SSMS simply not list these logins?

Comment: usr - that is good to know. So, it sounds like both a login and the user exist, but only the user is visible in SSMS?

Comment: Tony Hopkinson - it is SQL Server 2005. My bad for not mentioning that in the OP

Answer (score 4):

It is a server-level login unless you are connecting to a contained database. If you mean the database user that the server-level login maps to, you can find out using:

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM sys.server_principals AS l
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS u
ON l.sid = u.sid
WHERE l.name = 'user id in your connection string';
```

If you are not using a contained database, this is how you would provision your user:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN your_login_name 
  WITH PASSWORD = 'f00b@r!', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
USE your_database;
GO
CREATE USER your_login_name -- doesn't have to match, but should for sanity
  FROM LOGIN [your_login_name];
GO
-- then apply permissions of course.
```

Comment: If this legacy app was knocked up before roles became common place, then it's likely that user = role, e.g. StoresClerk, Purchaser etc.

Comment: Hi Aaron . . . I am assuming I am not using a Contained Database. I have actually not heard of Contained Databases till now, and I assume I am using 'normal' databases. If 'normal' databases are indeed contained, ie if "CREATE DATABASE etc" creates Contained Databases unless you specify otherwise, then I suppose the databases I am looking at might be Contained.

Comment: @BeanTaxi I really doubt that you would be using contained databases by accident and not know it. This is a new feature in SQL Server 2012 that, among other things, allows you to create a user that can connect directly to a database without needing a server-level login. You'd have to go out of your way to intentionally set this up.

Answer (score 1):

In general logins maps to a database user

So for instance if by some unfortunate circumstance the app expected database owner access

You'd create this here login on the server (if it's not already there) and then map it to the dbo user in the database in question.

If it's not a built in user, then you are going to have to look at a db that this legacy app can already access, find out which user it's mapped to
Create that user on your new DB, set the required permission roles etc
Then map the login to it.

There are some subtle differences between sql server versions, so it's hard to do a step by step

If the user the apps login maps to is a custom one, then you are going to have to figure out an equivalent in the new database. Doesn't have to have the same name though (unless the app is using that) and it could even have more permissions.